# Change CSS class based on current ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I am using jQuery `scrollTop()` to change the CSS class of a specific element based on how far down the page you one (one page website). However, this requires me to adjust the jQuery when the sections of the page grow larger in height.

Is there any good way to change the CSS class based on the current ID you are at in the page? or does it need to be based on how far down you are in terms of pixels?

This is the code I am currently using:

```
<script>

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop()>= 0 && $(this).scrollTop() < 550){
             $('.homeLink').addClass('selected');
         }
         else {
             $('.homeLink').removeClass('selected');
         }
    });

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop()>= 575 && $(this).scrollTop() < 1900){
             $('.photosLink').addClass('selected');
         }
         else {
             $('.photosLink').removeClass('selected');
         }
    });

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop()>= 1950 && $(this).scrollTop() < 3000){
             $('.aboutLink').addClass('selected');
         }
         else {
             $('.aboutLink').removeClass('selected');
         }
    });

</script>
```

It would be really cool to have it just change based on the ID it's at. Any ideas?

Comment: There's a few plugins that can do this easily if you don't want to do it in pure JS. [jquery.appear](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear) is the first that comes to mind.

Comment: I am still new to JS, any way you could elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: Elaborate on how to use the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the position of a target element with a certain ID, and change the behavior of the window scroll function based on whether you had reached that position yet.

```
// in window scroll function do this
var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
var elemTop = $('#someElement').position().top;
if (pos > elemTop) {
  doSomething();
}
```

For example, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LzwbR/)